# Laravel uploaded file isn't being saved to tmp path

Tags: php, laravel, file, nginx

Using Nginx and php7.2, uploading a file then moving it to another directory fails, the following message is shown:

```
(1/1) FileException
  The file "somefile.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.
```

I tracked the code and there is a function that fails `is_uploaded_file` the /tmp directory does not have any file I upload.

The form is written this way:

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'Controller@action', 'files' => true, 'id' => 'big-wizard', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) }}
```

I checked fpm configs and all upload options are on, even the `$_FILES` array has the file name and error code is 0

what can be the source of the problem?

Comment: Could it be that PHP doesn't have permission to upload to the `/tmp` folder?

Comment: @DerekPollard PHP-fpm is using my local user and it can create files in /tmp

Comment: Have you checked the PHP and nginx logs?

Comment: No Nginx errors, no fpm errors, only one Exception by laravel and its the `unknown error` one